# Eclipse: Enable "Open With" context menu option for .class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed a very useful [decompiler plugin](http://thewonggei.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/java-decompiler-and-its-missing-documentation/) for Eclipse. It's great, but like the standard class viewer in Eclipse, it only solves half of the problem: viewing the source of the classes.

When you go to File Associations and select the decompiler plugin as the viewer for .class, it decompiles all class files whether I have the source attached or not. If I use the standard Class viewer in Eclipse, the decompiler is never called. Right-clicking on the .class file doesn't allow you to select which viewer to use, as there isn't an "Open With" menu item.

Is there a way to enable the "Open With" context menu for .class files so I can select which plugin to use?

**EDIT:** I am using Indigo SR1, and this seems to happen only to .class files in a jar on the classpath. I get the "Open With" context menu for .class files that have been compiled from the project's source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .class entries you see in the project explorer for classes in jars aren't really files, so standard Eclipse file association doesn't work. There isn't anything you can do to make this action appear.

I recommend that you contact the developers of this decompiler plugin and explain your usecase. It will take work from the decompiler plugin developers and possible Eclipse JDT team you to get the feature that you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (no matter how disappointing the truth is in this case). I should see if someone else requested this as a feature from the JDT team as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get Open With for other file types, right?

My guess is that one of your plugins is causing the issue.  I get an "Open With" when I right click on .class files.  I can also add/remove different editors from its file association.

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1

Comment: I get "Open With" when I click on .class files on my file system (i.e. ones that compiled from my project in a target or bin directory). I don't get the same menu when I right-click on .class files in a jar from the classpath.

Have you tried both instances?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah, I'm not sure how to do that with referenced libraries.